# Why app crash when enter in landscape mode? kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle

If when the app switch to landscape mode the method onCreate() is recalled, why do I receive this error: `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property has not been initialized` only if the app enters in landscape mode but not in the portrait mode?

It sounds me that I need to clean some resources in onPause() or onStop() first to recall the onCreate()

My main activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

companion object {
    const val FILENAME = "file.txt"
    const val TAG = "APP"
}

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private lateinit var adapter: AdapterComuni

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    loadData()
    setUIControl()
}

private fun loadData() {
    val reader = assets.open(FILENAME).bufferedReader()
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        val listaComuni = ListaComuni()
        reader.useLines { lines ->
            lines.forEach {
                listaComuni.add(Comune(it))
            }
            launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
                listaComuni.listaComuni.sortBy { it.comune }
                launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "LETTO!")
                    adapter = AdapterComuni(
                        listaComuni
                    )
                    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
                    binding.rvComuni.layoutManager = layoutManager
                    binding.rvComuni.adapter = adapter
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun setUIControl() {
    binding.svComuni.setOnQueryTextListener(TextChangeListener())
}

inner class TextChangeListener: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(p0: String?): Boolean {
        return findAllSimilarCountry(p0)
    }

    override fun onQueryTextChange(p0: String?): Boolean {
        return findAllSimilarCountry(p0)
    }

}

private fun findAllSimilarCountry(p0: String?): Boolean {
    adapter.getFilter(binding.spnFilter.selectedItem.toString(), this).filter(p0)
    return true
}

}
```

The full error:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property adapter has not been initialized
    at com.user.app.MainActivity.findAllSimilarCountry(MainActivity.kt:73)
    at com.user.app.MainActivity.access$findAllSimilarCountry(MainActivity.kt:14)
    at com.user.app.MainActivity$TextChangeListener.onQueryTextChange(MainActivity.kt:67)
    at android.widget.SearchView.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1261)
    at android.widget.SearchView.access$2100(SearchView.java:99)
    at android.widget.SearchView$10.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1789)
    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:10069)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5938)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5776)
    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:122)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5733)
    at android.widget.TextView.onRestoreInstanceState(TextView.java:5601)
    at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:18820)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3883)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3883)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3883)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3883)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3883)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3883)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3883)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3883)
    at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:18798)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2234)
    at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1210)
    at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1164)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1338)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3470)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

`MainActivity.kt:73` is the line: `adapter.getFilter(binding.spnFilter.selectedItem.toString(), this).filter(p0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adaper is initialized only after the data is loaded (asynchronously) but `setUIControl()` is called before (while the data is still being loaded).

`setUIControl()` sets a `TextChangeListener` which accesses the adapter variable when `onQueryTextChange` is called.
When the search field is populated and the screen is rotated, Android restores the search field (`onRestoreInstanceState`) and thus triggers `onQueryTextChange`.

The solution is easy, just call `setUIControl()` after the RecyclerView is fully initialized (after the `binding.rvComuni.adapter`).